# Change width of a div without changing width of sibling div

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have 2 divs (div1, div2)
div 1 - There is a iframe inside (I really don't want to change this div width)
div 2 - target of change.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="div1" class="col-md-9">
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="col-md-3">
        (content)
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I need to change width of div2 (black box) without changing width of div1 (white box with red dot border).
[image]

I would like to use jquery animate for that

```
$('#div2').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $('#div2').animate({
    width:'?????'
  }, 500)
})
```

I was trying to do that alone, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And idea is to change the width of an inner div by using negative margin:

```css
iframe {
  width:100%;
}
#div2 {
  border:1px solid red;
  height:150px;
}

#div2 div {
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transition:1s all;
}
#div2:hover div{
  margin-left:-200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="div1" class="col-xs-9">
      <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="col-xs-3">
      <div>
      (content)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```